# jQuery on hover event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I have a site where I have some divs with hidden divs inside. What I am trying to do is to show the hidden divs when I hover over the parent div. I can't use CSS3's `:hover` because I need to support ie6. So I used jquery. which does not work for me.

Here is an example: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wtdh/4/)**

```
$('#front-container').on("hover", "#jobs-by-cat .job", function () {
    $(this).find('.hover').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

And this is how it should look on hover: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29jYf/1/)**

The `#jobs-by-cat` div is dynamically changed so the selection must be made like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no event called `hover`, the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function is a shortcut to register [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event handlers, so you need to use it

```
$('#front-container').on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#jobs-by-cat .job", function () {
    $(this).find('.hover').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eV78N/)

Answer (score 1):

As per the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for .on:

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, **removed in 1.9**: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single
>   event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.
>   Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method,
>   which accepts one or two functions

So you need to replace with mouseenter and mouseleave events:

```
$('#front-container').on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#jobs-by-cat .job", function () {
    $(this).find('.hover').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events.

```
$('#front-container').on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#jobs-by-cat .job", function () {
    $(this).find('.hover').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```